# Validating raster soil map through independent point set of soil attributes

Tags: maps, comparison, validation

If I have a raster map of pH, and a point (vector) dataset of map independent pH measurements, then how can I validate the accuracy of the existing raster with these extra measurements?

I don't have something specific in mind that's why I haven't something to attach.

Comment: 1st step would be to sample the raster at the independent points and plot them.

Comment: @user2856 thank you for your answer. Can you explain a bit further?How to sample the raster at the independent points?

Comment: That depends on the software or programming language/libraries you use. But the search terms "sample raster points your_software_or_library" is a start.

Comment: @user2856 do you have any specific comment about how to execute it in a GIS or in R? I am thinking about extract raster values to points and calculate statistics metrics such as RMSE, MAE.

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgisrastersampling